# How to download github's files were omitted from the list due to truncate directory?

Tags: github, git-clone

For downloading a folder in a GitHub repository, I’m getting this limitation.

> Sorry, we had to truncate this directory to 1,000 files. 1,078 entries
> were omitted from the list.

I know it’s

> only the display of files, they are still there.

But when I want to download it, just 1000 files can be downloaded.

Is there any way to see the omitted files? Files are there but not showing due to truncation. Even file finder not showing, omitted files.

How to download all files?